# French work permit holder: visa required for a visit to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, france, residency, chinese-citizens

I have a quite specific issue here : I am living and working in London (I am French), and my friend would like to come for a few days. The thing is, my friend is Chinese, but is working in France for a few years, so she has French work permit, does she need to apply for a "Standard Visitor visa" anyway?

Precision: I know that Schengen and UK have different types of visa, but as she has a long-time permit in France, can she be considered differently than just a Chinese citizen?

Comment: There are some others that could be nominated as the duplicate as well: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57425/non-eu-citizen-student-in-spain-holding-a-residence-permit-do-i-need-a-uk-visa or http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18720/do-i-need-both-a-uk-visa-and-a-schengen-visa

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it not a duplicate. The answer you seek is in all the linked questions (although the marked duplicate is the most explicit)

Comment: The answers to http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50745/uk-visa-requirement-residence-or-citizenship fully apply to your friend but there are enough differences to consider this question separately in my opinion.

Comment: When you say “my friend”, do you mean *a* friend or are you two romantically involved? If you can prove that you lived together for two years, my understanding is that your friend might qualify for an EEA family permit instead of a standard visitor visa.

Comment: @Relaxed I don't see any meaningful differences between an Italian non-citizen resident and a French non-citizen resident. Why is this question not a duplicate?

Comment: Your friend needs a visa, being a French resident does not make any difference for visits to the UK, with only one major exception: holders of a residence card as family member of an EU citizen, joining or accompanying said EU citizen in the UK, which is presumably not the case here.

Comment: @CMaster You're right, I reversed my actions. I got a little confused between the various links, one of the questions mentioned above was about a student, this one is about a work permit, it's not trivially obvious that the same rules would apply to both. I would definitely not consider that one a duplicate. But the “Residence or citizenship?” question is very similar, save for the country of residence.

Comment: Okay, thanks you both for your links and explanations, now I get it. I also was confused with the "Check if you need this visa if you’re visiting from outside the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland" sentence from the UK visa service. And this is indeed a romantic relationship, but we did not lived together that long ...